# Javascript Persisting image visibility with a cookie/checkbox

Tags: javascript, image, html, checkbox, persistence

this is my first question on Stack Overflow, I'm new to Javascript (have been teaching myself Python to get a feel for coding) and thought I'd try my hand at a simple web app to see how easy it is to translate my knowledge of Python into Javascript.

Basically the app will let you know when your favourite fruit etc is in season. So I have a list of checkboxes on one page 'fruitpicker.html' and corresponding images on another 'seasonalguide.html' (The images are just pictures of a calendar with the fruits season shaded etc).

I have a cookie that persists the checkbox state and a piece of external JS that toggles image visibility depending on the state of its corresponding checkbox.
Most of the cookie someone else was using on the web, so it works great, however the image vis JS is giving me trouble.

I've written what I think it should be but it didn't work and no matter how much I tinker around with it, nothing happens.

I'm sure it's something really dumb but anyway, here's the code...

The broken image vis JS:

```
function toggleVisibility(checkId, imageId) {
    var imgEl = document.getElementById(imageId);
    var checkEl = document.getElementById(checkId);
    if (checkEl.checked) {
        imgEl.style.visibility="hidden";
        imgEl.style.display="none";
    }
    else {
        imgEl.style.visibility="visible";
        imgEl.style.display="inline-block";
    }
  }
```

By the way, if the line: `var checkEl = document.getElementById(checkId);`
is deleted the code works but image state doesn't persist. This is as far as I have gotten.

A few of the checkboxes in fruitpicker.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Fruit Picker</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cookie.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="restorePersistedCheckBoxes();">

<label for=       "chklogo">Braeburn</label>
<input type=      "checkbox" 
       id=        "chkBraeburn"
             onChange=  "toggleVisibility('braeburnItem'); 
                   toggleVisibility('braeburnSeason');
                   persistCheckBox(this);" /><br>                   

<label for=       "chklogo">Fuji</label>
<input type=      "checkbox" 
       id=        "chkFuji" 
       onChange=  "toggleVisibility('fujiItem'); 
                   toggleVisibility('fujiSeason');
                   persistCheckBox(this);" /><br>

<label for=       "chklogo">Golden Delicious</label>
<input type=      "checkbox" 
       id=        "chkgolldenDelicious" 
       onChange=  "toggleVisibility('goldenDeliciousItem'); 
                   toggleVisibility('goldenDeliciousSeason');
                   persistCheckBox(this);" /><br>

<label for=       "chklogo">Granny Smith</label>
<input type=      "checkbox" 
       id=        "chkGrannySmith" 
       onChange=  "toggleVisibility('grannySmithItem'); 
                   toggleVisibility('grannySmithSeason');
                   persistCheckBox(this);"/><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the Seasonal Guide page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="imageVisibility.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img    id="imgGuide" 
        src="Images/Calendar/calendarHeader.png"
        align="left"/>

<img    id="braeburnItem" 
        src="Images/Produce/Fruit/BraeburnApple.png" 
        style="float:left; display:none;" />
<img    id="braeburnSeason" 
        float="top" 
        src="Images/InSeason/InSeasonApr.png"  
        align="left" 
        style="display:none"/>

<img    id="fujiItem" 
        src="Images/Produce/Fruit/FujiApple.png" 
        style="float:left; display:none;" />
<img    id="fujiSeason" 
        float="top" 
        src="Images/InSeason/InSeasonMar.png"  
        align="left" 
        style="display:none;"/>

<img    id="goldenDeliciousItem" 
        src="Images/Produce/Fruit/GoldenDeliciousApple.png"  
        style="float:left; display:none;"/>
<img    id="goldenDeliciousSeason" 
        src="Images/InSeason/InSeasonFeb.png"  
        align="left"
        style="display:none;"/>

<img    id="grannySmithItem" 
        src="Images/Produce/Fruit/GrannySmithApple.png"  
        style="float:left; display:none;"/>
<img    id="grannySmithSeason" 
        src="Images/InSeason/InSeasonApr.png" 
        align="left"
        style="display:none;"/><br>

<table width="170px" height="70px">
<tr>
    <td>
    <a href="Main.html" id="back" title="about" class="button">
    <img src="Images/Buttons/backButton.png" align="right">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The question was getting long so I didn't include the cookie, but I can if it's useful.
Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm noticing two issues here.

First off, you're using two separate pages, but `document.getElementById` can only access the elements of the page you're on. So, your lines:

```
var imgEl = document.getElementById(imageId);
var checkEl = document.getElementById(checkId);
```

have to fail, because they are trying to access elements in the two pages. Whichever page you're running the script on, one of those lines will return null. Your question doesn't describe how the two separate HTML files relate to each other, so I can't help you fix this (Does the first load the second whenever a checkbox is clicked, or are the two pages loaded in frames or iframes of a parent page?).

The second issue is that your `toggleVisibility` function is defined with two parameters, but your code (for example):

```
onChange=  "toggleVisibility('grannySmithItem'); 
               toggleVisibility('grannySmithSeason');
```

calls the method (twice) with only one parameter. If we're talking about the same function (you might have a different function definition on each of the two pages), then the function can never identify the correct image, because the `imageId` is never supplied.

Comment: Yeah, you're bang on with your first point. I've had it on the same page for the last month to test it, so I hadn't run into that problem yet. As for the structure, when the app is finished, they will be completely separate .html pages that do **not** link to eachother. To get to each of them you would have to navigate back to the index.html and then into the other eg. fruitpicker.html -> index.html -> seasonalguide.html. As for the second issue you pointed out as far as I know that piece of code works. Both the correct images show up when needed (Is this the issue you meant?).